# Combine 3000k txt files into one txt file Linux

Tags: linux, merge, cat

I want to combine 3000k txt files in one txt file
Tried this:

```
cat ./data/*.txt >>final1.txt
```

But this is gives an error

```
bash: /bin/cat: Argument list too long
```

How to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use find for that:

```
find ./data/ -name "*.txt" -exec cat "{}" \; >>final1.txt
```

`*` expansion has limits because bash expands it into every single filename and arguments are limited by kernel setting `MAX_ARGS_PAGES` (see http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6060)

Comment: You can use: `find ./data/ -name "*.txt" -exec cat "{}" + >>final1.txt` the reduce the calls to cat to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:-
`cat` command is for `concatenation` of mulitple files. But it too has some limits on no. of files as an arguments. You can try this:-

```
 for files in *.txt; do cat $files >> output.txt ;done
```

NOTE:- you must have space on your machine to accommodate single merged(big one) file and already existing files.

Comment: Your solution will have the exact same problem because it uses `*` in argument.

Comment: It should be `for file in *.txt ; do cat "$file" ; done > output.txt`

Comment: For the safer side, remove `ls` to not to see issues due to  `ls`. Thanks @hek2mgl

Comment: Also note the way how I redirect the output. I'm using `> output.txt` after(!) the loop